# How to display iPhone's status bar on Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools, statusbar

I am developing an app with Ionic (1 !) and using `ionic serve` to test it on Chrome. I'd like to display the iPhone's status bar (battery, time and connection) on Chrome dev tools device mode.

Any knows if Chrome can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a way inside of chrome dev tools. I've tried to find a good solution for a while, it is [in their own words](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) only 'for a first approximation'.

You can though, create the device with your specifications, [HERE's](https://www.danhendricks.com/2018/04/adding-iphone-galaxy-chrome-mobile-emulated-devices/) a more complete list of available devices, where you can also shorten the length to get the size without the space of the status bar (yeah, not useful for the latest gen).

To better QA on mobile devices, maybe try something like [Blisk](https://blisk.io/), BrowserStack, [Slant](https://www.slant.co/options/5247/~crossbrowsertesting-review)...

Or if it's for a screenshot, try something free like [responsinator](http://www.responsinator.com/).

gl