# RESPONSIVE WEB LOOKS DIFERENT ON DEV-TOOLS THAN ON ACTUAL PHONE

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I wanted to know if there is anything related to media queries i'm not aware of that is making my web projects look different on the dev tools and on a mobile device.
To be clear, I made a webpage and started adding media queries to make it responsive. I used chrome dev-tools to choose the iphone se as target and started re arranging each element till it looked as I expected. something like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1No2g.png)

but when I open the webpage on the actual phone it looks something like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlWnl.jpg)

here is the css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 330px ){ /*for iphone 5/se */

    #burter{
        top: 19vh;
        left: 24vw;
        font-size: 9vw;}
        
        #logo{
            width: 23vw;
            top: 17vh;
            left: 0vw;}
    
        #navtabs{
            top: 30vh;
            left: 2vw;
            flex-direction: row;
            height: 14vw;
            width: 88vw;}
        
        .divisor{
    
            width: 8%;}
    
    
        .tab{
    
            font-size: 4vw;}
    
        #imgside{
    
            display: none;}
    
        #sponsors{
    
            width: 88vw;
            height: 15vw;
            top: 40vh;
            left: 2vw;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
    
        .sponsimg{
            width: 14%;}
    
        #welcome{
    
            left: 28vw;}
    
        #welcome h2{
    
            font-size: 13vw;}
    
        #welcome p{
    
            width: 67vw;}
    
    
        .homecontainer{
    
            width: 64vw;
            left: 9vw;
            height: 43vh;
            top: 57vh;}
    
        .homeheader{
    
            font-size: 6vw;}
    
        .hometext{
    
            font-size: 3vw;
            line-height: 1.5;}
    
        #map{
    
            width: 70vw;
            left: 12vw;
            top: 53vh;
            height: 30vh;}
    
        #contactus{
    
            left: 26vw;
            top: 82vh;}
    
        #divmedia{
    
            width: 80vw;
            left: 7.7vw;
            bottom: 3vh;}
    
        .media{
    
            font-size: 9vw;}
    
        #menucontainer{
    
            top: 48vh;
            height: 75vh;
            width: 121vw;
            left: -14vw;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }
    }
```

and the html but most of the tings are created via vanilla js:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script defer  src="./main.js"></script>
    <title>Burter Burguer Inc.</title>
    <link rel = "icon" href = 
    "../images/burguerlogo/logo.png" 
            type = "image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA89atXDJHDp5fVs2YF-DB1fQXVbn3GgZM&callback=initMap">
    </script>

</head>
<body id="body">
        <div id="header">
            <img id="logo" src="../images/burguerlogo/logo.png">
            <h1 id="burter">BURTER INC.</h1>
            <div id="navtabs">
                <button id="homebutton" class="tab">HOME</button>
                <div class="divisor"></div>
                <button id="menubutton" class="tab">MENU</button>
                <div class="divisor"></div>
                <button id="contactbutton" class="tab">CONTACT</button>
            </div>
            <div class="removable" id="welcome">
                <h2>WELCOME</h2>
                <p>To your new favourite food...</p>
            </div>
                <img id="imgside" src="../images/Clever Photo Mashups by Stephen McMennamy.jpeg">
            <div id="sponsors">
                <img class="sponsimg" src="../images/mc_cain-removebg-preview.png">
                <img class="sponsimg" src="../images/cocacola-removebg-preview.png">
                <img class="sponsimg" src="../images/corona-removebg-preview.png">
                <img class="sponsimg" src="../images/heinz.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I looked for answers but couldn't find anything that could help me so I would really apreciate your help in order to fix these because I'm trying to build a portfolio but non responsive webs don't look good at all. Thank you !

Comment: Using `vh` units to position elements vertically is not a good idea. Let them flow. On your real phone, you have the address bar and the bottom menu that reduce the height of the viewport, which affects `vh`. If you select `Responsive` in your browser emulator and adjust the height, you will see the same result: https://imgur.com/a/iX9X0Ar

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't thought about the adress bar in that way. but the problem is that i Ddont know if i could leth them flow because i had all of them with position absolute, so i would need at least to use margins to locate them, shouldnt I ?

Comment: `position: absolute` is sometimes useful, but it makes it hard for multiple elements to work well together when varying the screen size, especially when both width and height come into play. If you let them flow, yes, you can use margins to ensure, for example, that the distance between the navbar and the sponsor bar remains what you want it to be. If you want elements to overlap (like your logo), you can use negative margins

Answer (score 2):

It might be because your positioning of the elements are based on viewport size, but the actual size of the elements aren't shrinking/expanding based on viewport. I personally wouldn't use vh units, but if you must, try shrinking the elements slightly as viewport dimensions get smaller.

Comment: thanks ! the elements are being resized but actually they change with the view width not the view height and that seems to be the problem as well, maybe i would set those measures to pixels instead(the ones of the resizong)

Comment: but the thing is how could I know when te elements are correctly placed in real life if the dev-tools are showing something different ?

Comment: find out the actual dimensions of the mobile viewport by subtracting the address bar and bottom menu. That might be difficult to do, take a look at the links mentioned in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402203/how-to-display-iphones-status-bar-on-chrome-dev-tools)